# strange behavior of QueryDict in request.POST django

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am experiencing a strange behavior of QueryDict in request.POST in Django. I am making a ajax-post request and trying to access a key `'Highest_Qualification'` in request.POST like this

`(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'Highest_Qualification': [u'1', u'2']}>
(Pdb) request.POST.get('Highest_Qualification')
u'2'
(Pdb) type(request.POST.get('Highest_Qualification'))
<type 'unicode'>`

Actually I am expecting `type(request.POST.get('Highest_Qualification')` to return `<type 'list'>` and not `<type 'unicode'>`

But when I do this

```
(Pdb) xx = dict(request.POST)
(Pdb) type(xx)
<type 'dict'>
(Pdb) xx['Highest_Qualification']
[u'1', u'2']
(Pdb) type(xx['Highest_Qualification'])
<type 'list'>
```

I get the expected type/behavior for key `'Highest_Qualification'`. I am not sure why this is happening. Any insight on why making dict(request.POST) works will be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The behavior is intended and documented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects .

The alternative method `.getlist(key, default)` will return the values as a list.

Answer (score 2):

Because a QueryDict is not a dict. In particular, it is intended to support the fact that a query can have multiple values for the same key, but that the most usual use case is to just get a single value.

When you know you can have multiple values for a key, you can use `getlist`:

```
request.POST.getlist('Highest_Qualification')
```

which correctly returns `[1, 2]`.